# User Management Feature

Tags: google-app-engine

This is a newbie question regarding app engine for Android. Is there any user management API for Android apps in the app engine?

What I'm looking for is something similar to what a mbaas provider like Kinvey provides. Something that I could use to do sing-ins, authentication, and possibly social integration (like FB).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google+ Signin](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) which integrates really easy with both Android and App Engine and supports most gmail accounts.